# Apahce Ignite sql temporary tables like sql using with function?

Tags: sql, ignite

Does Apache ignite allow creating temporary table the way sql does like

```
with temptable as (select * from table)

select * from temptable;
```

Answer (score 2):

This syntax doesn't seem to be supported.

But you can always use the equivalent construct:

```sql
SELECT temptable.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS temptable;
```